# CQRS design: nosql data view

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

This is a "language agnostic" question.
I started to study the CQRS pattern.

I've a simple question. I'm supposing to have 2 different storage layer: one relational for the commands(Mysql etc..) and one NoSql (mongo,cassandra.. etc) for the "query"?

Let me explain a little example:

1) As a user I want to insert a "Todo task"
   Command: "Create Task" and will insert a new task into a database which have the User and the   Todo tables.

2) As a user I'm able to see a list of created task
   Query: "GetTasks" that will return a "view" with a collection of task taken from a non sql table named "UserTasks" which have a user and a list of created task.

Is the right approach? I'm sorry if the language is poor, it's just a little example.
If it seems a good approach (again, don't consider details) what is the best approach to keep updated the data stores?

I'm thinking to raise an event like "TaskCreated" and take the new task and insert those information in the nosql storage.

Thanks!

Comment: CQRS doesn't require different persistence models, just different application models (Domain and Query). Depending on your app, you might use the same persistence model for both needs or you'll need specific persistence models for each. The point is, it's not a _must_ ,it's up to you to choose if 1 or 2 models are better for your app

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer Mike. Yes, as discussed above, I know that you can choose different solutions case by case. I am just curios if, in some cases, it's not a "cqrs design" violation using two different datastores, one for command and one for the query. If not, in that case, what is the best approach to keep the query data store updated with the "command" one?

Comment: CQRS = 1 Domain model and at least one Read model. That's it. Anything else is implementation detail. CQRS is just a principle, you decide how it will be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what you're looking for. but... typically, a command would be something that results in side effects. Queries don't cause side effects. GetTasks wouldn't really be a command, but a query.

Your "CreateTask" would be a command, which would result in the task added to the relevant data store(s). Your GetTasks query would retrieve that information from a datastore. It doesn't really matter if you're using a SQL or NoSQL store for this.

The "CommandStore" is typically the store that has just enough data to enforce invariants. In your case, what data is required for that? Is some information required to decide whether or not a task can be registered? For example, say, you have a requirement that a user can have at most 3 "todo"s. In this case, a table in the "Command Store" storing (UserId, Todo Count) is enough. You could also use (UserId, [TodoId]) - ie. store a list of todo ids so that you can gain idempotence. All other information about the user and tasks would be query data, and would be in the query store.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes "getTask" is a query (I modified immediately the mistake because I called it "CommandQuery" and I meant just a Query". My questions is, if has sense or not storing information in a sql database (information that coming from the commands) and meanwhile having a NoSql view of that informations. The nosql view is a store for the query and the information are modellate in a "query driven" way. Make sense?

Comment: Again, sql or nosql doesn't necessarily matter. What matters is the the command side store should only have information necessary to enforce invariants. That may mean some information that's in the query store, or it could be in a completely separate format altogether. It would depend on your particular business scenario.

Comment: Ok thanks! probably I didn't explain very well what I mean. I'm just saying: supposing if have a business scenario where the command stores information in a STOREA. And supposing the query takes information from the STOREB. Where STOREA != STOREB because in the information in STOREB are organized in another way, what is the best approach to keep the STOREB updated with the STOREA?I think that one of the benefits of CQRS is given by the separation of concerns between "write" actions and "Read" actions. Then, in some cases, I can separate the stores where the data are written or read.

Comment: There are MANY approaches, depending on guarantees, latencies, etc. If you need absolute up to the second consistency between A and B, you'll have to use some form of transaction coordinator supporting 3 phase commit (assuming a network between A and B). Quite often, a message queue / bus is used...A is updated and a message is published. A handler updates B. Another approach is to publish a msg and separate handlers update both A and B. Another approach is an event is published, which handlers poll to update viewmodel stores. This can be over ATOM for example. Lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

While there are times when you may wish to store commands, you generally don't. Rather a popular approach is to store the domain events that occur as a result of the commands.This is referred to as Event Sourcing. This would make 'STOREA' a store of events or to put it another way, an event stream. 'STOREB' is typically referred to as the Read Model. It has a de-normalised structure optimised for read speed. It is kept up to date via de-normalisers which respond to specific events. A key point to note here is that there is often a lag between the event being raised and the read model being updated. This in my opinion is a good thing but needs to be thought about when designing the UI.

For more info take a look at [CQRS – A Step-by-Step Guide to the Flow of a typical Application](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)

I hope that helps